# How to favorite a tweet that is displayed in my website using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pulling tweets from my twitter profile to my website. I'm adding REPLY, RETWEET and FAVORITE links beneath each of my tweet that I display on my website.

For reply, I can use an anchor tag like this.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=@<myTwitterName>a" target="_new">Reply</a>
```

For retweet, I will be using this. http://ejohn.org/blog/retweet/

But I cannot find a way to implement FAVORITE functionality, using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#favorite-intent

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=51113028241989632">Favorite</a>
```

More here in step 4:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-an-advanced-twitter-widget/

Answer (score 0):

Web Intents provide popup-optimized flows for working with Tweets & Twitter Users: Tweet, Reply, Retweet, Favorite, and Follow. They make it possible for users to interact with Twitter content in the context of your site, without leaving the page or having to authorize a new app just for the interaction.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents